# Sitecore 8.2 showing error attempt to access method 'Sitecore.Context+PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()' failed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore8.2

I have upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 8.2. I have a method in which I am using:

```
Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor
```

For this it is giving error:

```
attempt by method METHOD_NAME to access method 'Sitecore.Context+PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()' failed.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The

> Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor

Is deprecated in the Sitecore.Kernel since Sitecore 8.0 Update-6 see the [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2080%20Update6/Release%20Notes):

> Deprecated and removed functionality
>
> The properties IsPageEditor, IsPageEditorDesigning and
>   IsPageEditorEditing in the class Context.PageMode from Sitecore
>   namespace have been deprecated in favor of the new introduced
>   properties IsExperienceEditor and IsExperienceEditorEditing. Old
>   properties will be removed in one of the future major versions.
>   (438475)

In Sitecore 8.2 update 1 the Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor is removed 
use

> Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor

Same for:

```
IsPageEditor, Obsolete Use IsExperienceEditor instead
IsPageEditorClassic, Deprecated always false
IsPageEditorDesigning, Obsolete Use IsExperienceEditorEditing instead
IsPageEditorEditing, Obsolete Use IsExperienceEditorEditing instead 
IsPageEditorNavigating, Deprecated always false
```